# TypeError: start() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Tags: python

```
class mainmenu(object):
    def __init__(self, screen):
        pygame.init()
        self.screen = screen    
    def button(self, rect, radius=0, action=None):
        click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
        if rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
            color = (141,182,205)
            if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
                action()
        else:
            color = (28,134,238)
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, color, rect, border_radius = radius)
    def menu(self):
        screenw = self.screen.get_width()
        screenh = self.screen.get_height()
        mid_w = screenw/2
        mid_h = screenh/2
        btn_start = pygame.Rect(mid_w-150,mid_h*3/5,300,100)
        self.button(btn_start, 50, self.start)
    def start():
        return 'start'
```

I don't give any arguments in `start()` but I catch this error

```
TypeError: start() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Comment: `self.start()` is a shorthand for writing `start(self)`. So you can't pass in a method that's bound to an object, you'll have to pass in a free function (or static method). If you look at `start`, you'll see it expect `self` as a parameter.

Comment: just add `self` in `start()` like `start(self)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self.start()` is shorthand for writing `start(self)`. So you can't pass in a method that's bound to an object, you'll have to pass in a free function (or static method). All methods on a class expects the argument `self` (your `start` method shouldn't work).

```
class Example:
    def method(self):  # Takes `self` as parameter
        pass
```

Instead, you must create a static method that doesn't take any parameters:

```
class Example:
    @staticmethod
    def my_static_method():
        # Doesn't take `self` as parameter, which means you cannot use
        # `self` in this method.
        pass
```

or a free-standing function that's not bound to a class at all.

```
def my_function():
    pass
```

These can be passed as functions that doesn't take any arguments.

In your specific case, you can make `start` a static method, as it doesn't use `self`, or a free function:

```
class MainMenu:
    def __init__(self, screen):
        pygame.init()
        self.screen = screen    
    
    def button(self, rect, radius=0, action=None):
        click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
        if rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
            color = (141,182,205)
            if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
                action()
        else:
            color = (28, 134, 238)
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, color, rect, border_radius=radius)
    
    def menu(self):
        screen_width  = self.screen.get_width()
        screen_height = self.screen.get_height()
        mid_width  = screen_width  / 2
        mid_height = screen_height / 2
        btn_start = pygame.Rect(mid_width-150, mid_height*3/5, 300, 100)
        
        # Do this to call the static method.
        self.button(btn_start, 50, MainMenu.start)

        # Or do this to call the free standing function.
        self.button(btn_start, 50, start)
    
    @staticmethod
    def start():
        return 'start'

def start():
    return 'start'
```